# How to plot data imported from a csv?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to import CSV output data from a simulation into an Excel sheet to plot the data in a regular XY scatter chart.

I managed everything except the end result. The data is imported from csv to Excel, points are replaced by commas as a decimal separator.

It is plotting a straight horizontal line at 0 y-coordinates.
[image: Resulting chart]

I noticed that the values in Excel are stored as texts, although I specified the format for numerical contents of csv as numbers like following:

```
DataSheet.Cells(Row, col).NumberFormat = "0.E+00"
```

When I test `Isnumeric(cell.value)`, it turns out positive.

My complete code:

```
CsvFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Set DataSheet = Worksheets("CSV_Plot")
nrow = 10 'data starts at 10th row
Open CsvFile For Input As #1

Do Until EOF(1)
Line Input #1, CsvLine
CsvItem = Split(CsvLine, ",")
If Not CsvItem(0) <> "" Then GoTo 10 'ignores first line
ncol = UBound(CsvItem) 'ncol = number of data columns
    If IsNumeric(CsvItem(0)) Then
    
    For i = 0 To ncol
    CsvItem(i) = Replace(CsvItem(i), ".", ",") 'replace point with comma in 'numerical values
    Next i
     
    End If
Add1 = DataSheet.Cells(nrow, LBound(CsvItem) + 1).Address
Add2 = DataSheet.Cells(nrow, ncol + 1).Address

DataSheet.Range(Add1 & ":" & Add2) = CsvItem


nrow = nrow + 1
10:
    Loop
nrowlast = nrow

Close #1



For Row = 11 To nrowlast
    For col = 1 To ncol
    DataSheet.Cells(Row, col).Select
    DataSheet.Cells(Row, col).NumberFormat = "0.E+00"   
      
    Next col

Next Row

Set ChtObj = DataSheet.ChartObjects.Add(50, 50, 500, 300)
  Set Cht = ChtObj.Chart
  
  With Cht
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = DataSheet.Range("A11:A35")
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = DataSheet.Range("N11:N35")
    
      
  End With
```

Comment: Please post all the relevant code you are using to generate the graph.

Comment: thanks @M.Schalk...I have added the code now

Comment: So does the code output the correct values to `DataSheet.Range("A11:A35")` and `DataSheet.Range("N11:N35")`?

Comment: yes...it does. When I test it with Isnumeric and output the value of sum of all values in the range in a msgbox, it returns correct values.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: What happens if you don't replace the periods with commas? VBA understands numbers with periods as decimal separators, and if it moves those values into cells formatted with comma decimal separators, the conversion just happens. Changing the periods to commas in VBA might turn the values into text, which then remain as text in the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I think your problem is this line: `CsvItem = Split(CsvLine, ",")`. The return type of `Split` should be a `String`. I don't know what your data looks like but you could try casting it as `Double` if decimal places are relevant. Otherwise cast it as `Long`: `CsvItem = CLng(Split(CsvLine, ","))`.

Original answer:
I updated the relevant parts of your code:

```
For Row = 11 To nrowlast
    For col = 1 To ncol
        DataSheet.Cells(Row, col).NumberFormat = "0.E+00"
    Next col
Next Row
```

I took out the `.Select` statement as it is unnecessary and might lead to errors. Here is the main part part:

```
Dim ChtObj As Object

Set ChtObj = DataSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(, xlXYScatterLines, 50, 50, 500, 300)

With ChtObj.Chart
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = DataSheet.Range("A11:A35")
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = DataSheet.Range("N11:N35")
End With
```

This should work as intended.

Comment: thank you @M.Schalk but it didnt solve the problem. I am still getting the same result. I cant understand why the numbers appear as text in excel (where I cant perform sum or any calculation) whereas within VBA code I can perform calculations on them.

Comment: @ShS So the values put into the cells are not formatted correctly? Have you tried reformatting them by hand? If it's the formatting that's wrong, fixing the formatting manually should fix it. If that works then we should take a look at the formatting in your code.

Comment: as I said, data in the excel are texts, so any manual formatting doesnt work on it. The only way is either I convert them to number (with text to columns tool) or copy their values to another sheet (with  =value(A11:A35) for example). But I want to manage all of it from within the code, as the data are quite big.

Comment: thank you @M.Schalk for your efforts. Unfortunately it didnt solve the problem. I found a way after some effort which I have posted below as answer. Thank you once again.

Comment: Huh, I thought I had located the source of your problem with my edit at the top. Anyway, glad it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

After some effort, i was able to locate the source of problem: I had defined `CsvItem()` as string and that's why when I execute the statement `DataSheet.Range(Add1 & ":" & Add2) = CsvItem`, the values in excel were always text irrespective of the format.

The solution to this was to define a variable to hold numerical values of CsvItem and assign this value to excel cells:

```
Dim CsvVal() As Double
CsvVal(i) = CDbl(CsvItem(i))
DataSheet.Range(Add1 & ":" & Add2).Value = CsvVal
```

this eventually produced the result I wanted.